# group data by same timestamp using cosmos db sql

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Question:
I am trying SQL query as the image showed below，I want it to be grouped by the same timestamp
[image]

expected output:

```
[  
   {
      "tag1": {
        "TagName": "PV1-input-power-L(10W)",
        "Value": 0
       },
       "tag2": {
        "TagName": "Sunshine-Display-Value",
        "Value": 0
       },
       "tag3": {
        "TagName": "TotalEnergy-(100kWh)_1",
        "Value": 0
       },
      "timestamp": "2020-03-27T02:40:18Z"
    }
 ]
```

sample document:

[image: document structure]

[image: tag]

Comment: I think this will be easier to accomplish if you will create a sproc.

Comment: @HasanSavran My Collection is kinda unusal due to IoThub 4K file limit , one document is split into two. As you refer sproc , just wonder if it can make two document into one before any other operation?

Comment: I don't believe sproc can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use User Defined Functions.

Here is the data from my containers
[image: My Data in Cosmos]

Here is the function I have created. I named it CustomArray.

```
function userDefinedFunction(input){
var obj={};
input.forEach(function(element,index){ 
obj["tag"+index] = {
    TagName :element.TagName,
    Value: element.Value
};
}); return obj;}
```

Here, I run the UDF with my select statement
[image]

It returns the following data.

[image]

Schema is very close to what you are looking for. I think you can make it better by changing some jscript in UDF.
I hope this helps!